# 'Pulling in' a div from the inside?

Tags: css

Not sure if this is even remotely possible, but asking anyway. I have a div with a fixed height and width that I cannot edit. I can, however, add in child elements. Is there a way to only use child elements to shrink the size of the parent?

And I can only use inline css, with no js or jquery.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: I cannot possibly imagine such a scenario haha, but let's go with it....

Comment: You can only overlap the div i guess. But thats not clean at all

Comment: ...or put another div inside it that's smaller etc. The whole thing is mental haha

Comment: Share some html, there is nothing impossible for javascript and jquery in web

Comment: as @Traver suggest it can be done with jQuery many ways, but its just so hacky and frankly silly that I urge you to solve the underlying problem or seemingly having no access to (some) of the markup!

Comment: how are you adding child elements?

Comment: Is the `div` originally empty (like so: `<div ></div>`)

Comment: Can't use js or jQuery, unfortunately.

Comment: @Danield Yes, it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original `div` is empty (see comments), instead of setting the default fixed width/height on all states of the div - you could set these properties only for the empty state of the div using the [empty pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty).

This way, when the `div` gets children added - those original fixed widths don't apply anymore.

```css
div:empty {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<hr>
<div>
<p>some text</p></div>
```

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that I can only do inline.

Comment: How about using a `<style>` tag: `<style>
  div:empty {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
</style>` - https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/EmggEE

Comment: Can't do that either. Looks like there isn't a solution to this, in my case.